# Send email depending on selected option in Contact form

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, contact-us, send-mail

I have created a custom select in contact form (Contact Us page). Is it possible to send an email to a different email address depending of the selected option? **i.e.** if i choose 'Area 1' the email is sent to area1@mail.com, if i choose 'Area 2' is sent to area2@mail.com and so on.

[image: Select option]

I have seen that the email address to which the email is sent is obtained from **system.xml** in contact module.

The trace i have made is:

/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
            ->getTransport();
```

I understand that in the code above is where the transport object is created to send the email. I also know that the email is defined in the next piece of code:

```
->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
```

The value of that constant is 'contact/email/sender_email_identity'.

So, following that path to the system.xml i encountered the field **sender_email_identity**.

In there, they use a source model to obtain the email.

```
<source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
```

In the Identity.php file is the ***toOptionArray( )*** function.

```
/**
 * Retrieve list of options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    if ($this->_options === null) {
        $this->_options = [];
        /** @var $section \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section */
        $section = $this->_configStructure->getElement('trans_email');

        /** @var $group \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group */
        foreach ($section->getChildren() as $group) {
            $this->_options[] = [
                'value' => preg_replace('#^ident_(.*)$#', '$1', $group->getId()),
                'label' => $group->getLabel(),
            ];
        }
        ksort($this->_options);
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
```

Yet, i don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: On basis of Dropdown select value you can set Yes. Add Area wise Config Variable in `system.xml`. Start with static email giving.

Comment: @Ankit If i understand correctly the idea would be to replace the <source_model></source_model> tag with my own right? How would i do that, i mean, not to replace in the core file but specify a system.xml of my own that use my custom source_model.